# Is that possible to run the image ubuntu 14.04 64 bits-Oracle 11g in virtual box in parallel in mac?

Tags: virtualbox

I am using a macbook pro 13" 2014 mid version.
Parallel desktop 13 is installed in my mac.
The parallel is running window 10 64bits version.
In the parallel, virtual machine 64bits version is installed. 
I tried to run an image of ubuntu 14.04 64 bits-Oracle 11g  in the virtual machine.

This is the error I get:

VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.

I have tried to go to the setting of image -> system but the acceleration is not able to be selected to change the setting.

Is that possible to run the image ubuntu 14.04 64 bits-Oracle 11g in virtual box in parallel in mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parallels Desktop** provides nested virtualization support (Intel VT-X technology) that allows you to run virtual machines inside **Windows 10**, 8 and Windows Server 2012 virtual machines.

To enable Hyper-V support in Parallels Desktop Pro and Business Edition:

Go to *Actions* menu -> *Configure* -> *Hardware* -> *CPU & Memory*. Click the gray downward pointing triangle ▼ to expand *Advanced Settings* and tick the *Enable nested virtualization* checkbox (enclosed in a red rectangle in the below screenshot).

[image]
<sup>**Parallels Desktop 13**</sup>

#### In Windows 10

1. Open VirtualBox, select the Ubuntu 14.04 guest OS, and click the gear-shaped *Settings* icon ⚙️ in the VirtualBox toolbar.
2. You will see a guest OS Settings window that looks like this.

[image]

3. Select *System* from the left pane of the Settings window.
4. Select the *Acceleration* tab.
5. After where it says *Paravirtualization Interface*, click the downward pointing triangle and from the dropdown menu select *Default*.
6. After where it says *Hardware Virtualization*, check the checkbox to the left of where it says *Enable VT-x/AMD-V*.
7. Click the *OK* button in the lower right corner to enable the changes.